# Why does my loop stop after one iteration?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, loops, directory

I'm struggling to see why my loop stops after one iteration.

My code:

```
import os

def open_data(fpath):
    counter=0
    for i in os.listdir(fpath):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(fpath,i)):
            #print counter
            f=open(os.path.join(fpath,i),"r")
            #counter=counter+1
    return counter,f.readlines()
            #f.close()
x=open_data("C:/Users/manchester/.ipynb_checkpoints/txt_sentoken/practice_")
```

Basically I am trying to loop through all files in my directory which contain movie reviews. I am first aiming to read all files from the directory using a function then I need to take say 70% of the reviews for training 10% for testing 10% for validation 10% for hyperparamters sample. But I just can't get over this first hurdle of trying to read all files using a function.

I have tried using list and append but this does not work either.

Comment: why do you think your loop stops after only one iteration? This loop should run for as many iterations as there are files in the given location, but you'd never know since you discard everything but the result of the final iteration.

Comment: Not sure if it's the issue, but you never close `f` after opening it

Comment: This seems like a good time to learn some basic debugging. You should look at the values of the different variables and terms inside the loop, and after the loop, to see what your code is actually doing.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed)

Answer (score 0):

You are not reading all the files you are only opening all the files, in the same variable and in the end when you are doing `f.readlines()` `f` it's only whatever was your last file, you should read all in a "buffer" and in the end return it

It should be something like this

```
def open_data(fpath):
    counter=0
    all_lines = []
    for i in os.listdir(fpath):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(fpath,i)):
            all_lines += open(os.path.join(fpath,i),"r").readlines()
            counter=counter+1
    return counter,all_lines
```

Keep in mind that reading lot's of eventually big files will add up in memory, you'd better with using a generator if your code allows it

```
def get_lines(fpath):
    for i in os.listdir(fpath):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(fpath,i)):
            for line in open(os.path.join(fpath,i),"r"):
                yield line
# this would give you an iterable over all the lines in all the files, one line at a time
```

Later edit:
I have a folder "x" with 2 files "f1" and "f2"; "f1" contains the numbers 1,2,3 one per line while "f2" contains the numbers 4,5,6

```
>>> print open_data(".\\x") # gives
(2, ['1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5\n', '6\n'])
```

using the generator, you won't have the list of all the lines, but an "iterable", you could call it "lazy-reader", in order to use it you have to iterate over it

```
>>> for line in get_lines(".\\x"):
...    print line  # will give
1

2

3

4

5

6
```

the extra line between the numbers is the `\n` read from the files printed along the `\n` the print adds

Answer (score 0):

Well this way the code is only going to return the last file of the directory.

You are not doing anything on the files opened, and then returning the last one.

I guess you should append the `f.readlines` in a list and then return the list at the end  of the function.

The counter should work though, returning the number of files in the directory